# How does Service Container know when a constructor is triggered to resolve its dependencies?

Tags: laravel, laravel-service-container

For example I have a class named `User` and in its constructor I have a dependency named `MyDependency`.
MyDependency does not have any dependencies itself so I don't need to bind it to he `$app` container.

When I instantiate the `User` class with no constructor parameters, where does laravel know that a constructer is triggered and it must resolve its dependencies?

I know that Service Container uses ReflectionClass to instantiate the Dependency. But there must be some function which gets triggered to perform this.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. You have to explicitly call `App::make()` to create an instance. The same goes for calling other methods using `App:call()`.
Here's the relevant section of the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#the-make-method

**UPD**
Assume the following controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Order;
use App\Services\OrderService;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    protected OrderService $service;

    public function __construct(OrderService $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function update(Order $order)
    {
        return $this->service->update($order);
    }
}
```

The contents of OrderService:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Order;

class OrderService {
    public function __construct(bool $dry) { /* */ }
    public function update(Order $order) { /* */ }
}
```

In your service provider you have:

`$this->app->when(OrderService::class)->needs('$dry')->give(false);`

And in your `routes/api.php`

`Route::get('/order/{order}', [OrderController::class, 'update']);`

Now what happens when make a request to `api/order/1`? First, the `OrderController` instance is created. You provided the class name when registering the route, so Laravel knows which class to use. The instances is created with a call of `make`. As you mention in the quetion, reflections are used to determine, what arguments are expected by the constructor. In our case it's just the instance of `OrderService`.
So now Laravel will try to resolve this dependency. It's a class, not an interface, so Laravel will simply try to create it's instance, again using `make`. Again, analysing the constructor it will determine that it needs boolean parameter `$dry`. For which we have registered a resolver in our service provider.
So `$dry` gets passed to the `OrderService` constructor, Laravel gets an instance and passes it to `OrderController` constructor. Now it can call the `update` method.
By the same logic, the `call` method is used to resolve all dependencies. In this case it's just model dependency, which Laravel can resolve out of the box.

The general idea here is that `make` and `call` are always being called somewhere under the hood. There's no mechanism to intercept a native call to constructor or method. For example, if you modify `routes/api.php` like this:

```
Route::get('/order/{order}', function($order) {
    $controller = new OrderController();
    return $controller->update($order);
});
```

You'll get an ArgumentCountError for the constructor call.

Comment: But laravel documentations says: If a class has no dependencies or only depends on other concrete classes (not interfaces), the container does not need to be instructed on how to resolve that class.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#zero-configuration-resolution

Comment: @Abw This isn't exactly about your original question. If your class constructor expects a parameter and you try to create an instance of it using `new MyClass` you will get an Exception anyway. What the documentation says here is that if you call `make` method, laravel will first try to resolve dependencies automatically.

Comment: For example I have a route which triggers createOrder function in my controller. This function has a PaymentOrder dependency. So when does `make` method get called so that laravel tries to resolve my dependency? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I've modified my answer and added an example. TLDR, the call happens somewhere under the hood, which is enabled by the fact, that you provide class and method names, when registering the route. I'd recommend you to experiment with using `make` and `call` vs calling methods directly.